# How to read values from model and keep in an array

Tags: angularjs

I have two model variables

```
$scope.itemsToSendPhase1 = itemX001;itemX002;itemX003
$scope.itemsToSendPhase2= itemY001;itemY002;itemY003
```

I am trying to keep these values in an array

```
itemX001
itemX002
itemX003
itemY001
itemY002
itemY003
```

Here is my Html code:

```
<input type="text"  ng-model="itemsToSendPhase1"/>
<input type="text"  ng-model="itemsToSendPhase2"/>
```

how to keep these values in an array?

Comment: It makes no sense to have those in an array and have that variable as an ng-model of a text input. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @OmriAharon it makes perfect sense if you're trying to insert something like tags/labels or any other character-delimited list and want to keep it inside a single input.

Comment: I have two text inputs and I am trying to read these values and trying to call service. service expecting parameters like this:dat.payload={

Comment: id:id,itemToSend:itemsToSend,here it is expecting array.

Comment: @hanu this is exactly what `ng-list` is used for, keeping a model as an array while allowing it a single input field, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to do here, BUt you can split the values in some other variable and store it as an array

`$scope.itemsToSendPhase1Array = $scope.itemsToSendPhase1.split('/;');`

now $scope.itemsToSendPhase1Array will have  [itemX001,itemX002,itemX003];

Comment: it worked for me. Thank you so much for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Check out `ng-list`.  If used in combination with an input and `ng-model` you can essentially utilize a singular input for an array of items.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="list" ng-list=", " ng-trim="true"/>
```

- docs - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngList
- codepen - http://codepen.io/jusopi/pen/YwaXRr